# Open CMD with specific color and title

Tags: batch-file, scripting, command, prompt

I recently started learning batch and wanted to write a script that opens CMD with a specific color and title. This code opens my CMD and another plain one! How can i get rid of the plain cmd?

```
Start CMD
title Hacker's CMD
color 04
```

Comment: Might I suggest `color a` for more of a "hacker" feeling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
start cmd /k title Hacker's CMD^&color 04
```

The `/k` parameter executes the commands and leaves the cmd window open. To pass several commands use an escaped command separator `^&` so that the separation occurs in the launched cmd, not in the original batch file.